# SNMP java API snmpbulkwalk

Tags: java, snmp

I'm studing a module to manage a router with protocol SNMP. I'm checking adventnet and snmp4j apis but I need to make some snmp calls in java via the command snmpbulkwalk. Is there any api in java to execute this command?

Comment: snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c public <IP> <Counter> this is the command in net-snmp framework

Comment: in php snmprealwalk — Return all objects including their respective object ID within the specified one [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmprealwalk.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SNMP4j to do SNMPBULKWALK on the router. SNMP4j provides below API to retrieve entire subtree of a given rootnode synchronously.

Class: TreeUtils.java
Method: getSubtree(targetV2, rootOID);

It also provides another method which is asynchronous.

Class: TreeUtils.java
Method: walk(targetV2, rootOIDs);

I have a github project which has the complete working code. You can clone the [repo](https://github.com/jineshmathewt/snmpbulkwalk) and try it.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for 1 minute and found [enter link description here](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/Snmp.html) and [enter link description here](http://techdive.in/snmp/snmp4j-snmp-get-example) to start from.

Comment: thanks for your reply about single get command the implemetation is easy,  my question is: "There is a library that implements the command snmpbulkwalk", because I need to take all the values ​​of a counter on all interfaces.